# Как вывести дату без точек, с пробелами?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно вывести дату в формате `среда, 19 4 2017` именно с пробелами.

Пытаюсь так:

```js
var date = new Date();

    var options = {
        year: 'numeric',
        month: 'numeric',
        day: 'numeric',
        timezone: 'UTC',
        weekday: 'long',
    };

    var day = date.toLocaleString("ru", options);  

    $('#js-date').text(day);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span class="date" id="js-date"></span>
```

Но выводит с точками.

А так (задаю `era: 'short',`), выводит еще и лишние строки (г. н. э):

```js
var date = new Date();

    var options = {
        year: 'numeric',
        month: 'numeric',
        day: 'numeric',
        timezone: 'UTC',
        weekday: 'long',
        era: 'long',
    };

    var day = date.toLocaleString("ru", options);  

    $('#js-date').text(day);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span class="date" id="js-date"></span>
```

**Вопрос**: как можно вывести дату в формате `среда, 19 4 2017` убрав при этом вывод `Г. Н. Э.` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var date = new Date();
var day = date.toLocaleString("ru", {weekday: 'long'}) + ', ' + date.getDate() + ' ' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + ' ' + date.getFullYear();  

$('#js-date').text(day);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span class="date" id="js-date"></span>
```

Comment: Спасибо, отличное решение, как-то не подумала о нем)